# Nhibernate QueryOver Representation of GroupBy in an inner join

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

So I'm new to Nhibernate having come from EF. After trying out Query<> and being massively underwhelmed by the lack of supported functions and nonsensical sql, I'm trying out QueryOver but not getting far. Can someone help me with a QueryOver representation of this SQL?

```
select p2.* from
   PurchaseOrders p2 inner join 
   (SELECT po.PurchaseOrderID, MAX(POS.StatusDate) as LastUpdate FROM PurchaseOrders Po 
   inner join PurchaseOrderStatuses POS on PO.PurchaseOrderID = pos.PurchaseOrderID 
   where pos.StatusID = :@status and po.SupplierID = :@supplierId
   group by po.PurchaseOrderID) p1
   on p2.PurchaseOrderID = p1.PurchaseOrderID
```

Comment: You won't be able to join on a table expression like that in QueryOver, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've put my current solution (after a LOT of playing) below. It doesnt quite follow this query to the letter but has a similar result, if you can think of an improvement, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Current solution looks like this but needs further work:

```
 int supplierId = 20;
         Status.StatusesEnum status = Status.StatusesEnum.Complete;

         PurchaseOrder orderAlias = null;

         IList<PurchaseOrder> orders =
                 Session.QueryOver<PurchaseOrder>(() => orderAlias).WithSubquery
                   .WhereExists(QueryOver.Of<PurchaseOrderStatus>()
                      .Where(c => c.PurchaseOrder.Id == orderAlias.Id)
                      .OrderBy(c=>c.StatusDate)
                      .Desc
                      .Select(c=>c.Status.Id == (int)status)
                      .Take(1)
                      //.Having status = statusID
                      )
                   .Where(o=>o.Supplier.Id == supplierId)
                   .List<PurchaseOrder>();
```